# Fitting retention data to an exponential curve in R and integrating it

Tags: r, lifetime, exponential, estimation

Hi I am trying to estimate the lifetime value of a game, here is what i have as data:
1 Day retention rate: 65%
7 Day retention rate: 30%
30 Day retention rate: 12%
365 Day retention rate: 2%

First I tried to plot the points but got an error: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

The rate seems to exponential and I want to fit a curve and later integrate it so I can estime the lifetime.

Appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to be mixing a number of things. With respect to the chart:

1. If you are working in *RStudio* the error may appear as your *plots* panel may be too small. Try to expand it.
2. Try changing the plot margin settings to: `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))`

---

Separate part of the problem pertains to curve fitting or whatever else you want to do with respect to the analysis. If you want to get some interest in that aspect of your problem, I would recommend that you post a reproducible example with some data and the corresponding code.